# Laravel check current time is between two times

Tags: php, laravel, time

Well , i've tried every solution on the net conserning this problem but always the same  result : **false**.

I'm trying to check exactly if current time is between ***10 pm*** and ***6 am*** at the same night , but all the solutions are returning false!!

For example , if i check between ***8 am*** and ***13 pm*** it works ! But only it's not working with the example i've given earlier.
Any solutions guys ?

Edit : here is one of the examples i've tried

```
@php
$now = Carbon::now();
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString("22:00 pm")
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString("06:00 am");
@endphp


@if ($now->between($start, $end))
 //approved
@else
//not approved
@endif
```

**Update:** Problem solved finally , and here is the code for those who faced or will face this problem in the future :

```
@php
$now = Carbon::now();
$curr = date('a'); //return am or pm
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString("22:00"); //init the start time
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString("06:00"); //init the end time

if ($curr == 'am'){
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString("22:00")->subDay();
//check if we are in the morning or after midnight , and go to yesterday datetime
}
else{
//then  we are in the evening or afternoon  , so add a day to get tomorrow's datetime
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString("06:00)->addDay();
}
@endphp


@if ($now->between($start, $end,true))
 //approved
@else
//not approved
@endif
```

**PS: im sure my code is not wrong i've been verifying it since days!**

Comment: What exactly do you mean `10pm` and `6am` because on your example it became `8 am` .You added a space as if they are the same !! witch is 100% not … finally please provide us with code aboute what you have done so far so we can get an idea aboute your issu .

Comment: I've provided a code example , to make it clear , i want to do some logique when the time is between 10 pm and 06 am in the same night

Comment: what happened if you specify dates on your createFromString call?

one option will be to get time only on the $now..

instead of Carbon::now() you can do something like 
$now = getTimeOnly(Carbon::now())
you have to create this function getTimeOnly where you get the current time out of the $now object.

Comment: thanks all for your help , i've solved the problem and the code is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the problem :

```
@php
$now = Carbon::now();
$curr = date('a'); //return am or pm
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString("22:00"); //init the start time
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString("06:00"); //init the end time

if ($curr == 'am'){
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString("22:00")->subDay();
//check if we are in the morning or after midnight , and go to yesterday datetime
}
else{
//then  we are in the evening or afternoon  , so add a day to get tomorrow's datetime
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString("06:00)->addDay();
}
@endphp


@if ($now->between($start, $end,true))
 //approved
@else
//not approved
@endif
```